# 603 Declined event is coming while hangup on incoming call with sipML5 but after 4-5 sec again I am getting incoming call

Tags: twilio, asterisk, bandwidth, sipml5

I am using asterisk 15.5 as voip server and twillio trunk to make outgoing and incoming call but when I hangup on an incoming call to sip client then 603 Declined event is coming to asterisk but after 4-5 sec again I am getting incoming call repeatedly. is it the issue with twilio trunk or 603 delined does not getting propogated?

Answer (score 0):

You can go under your [Twilio Call Logs](https://www.twilio.com/console/voice/calls/logs), click the particular Call(Sid) in question, and view the public packet capture (pcap), to see what Asterisk is sending back to Twilio. Twilio should not be resending the INVITE / advancing to the next origination URI (if configured) if receiving a 603 response from Asterisk, so most likely Asterisk is sending some other response code. You could also look at Asterisk logs to determine same.

Source: https://www.twilio.com/docs/sip-trunking#multiple-orig-uris
"Note: If any of the following SIP status codes are returned ("2xx", "400", "404", "405", "410", "416", "482", "484", "486", "6xx"), Twilio will not fail over to the next origination SIP URI. If there is no SIP response from a given server, Twilio will fail over after 4 seconds."

It is possible the carrier is retrying. You should be able to see this if there are multiple CallSID's which indicates the carrier sent it to Twilio multiple times.

Comment: whenever asterisk is getting 603(declined) from sip phone. it is sending 503 (service unavailable) to twilio.